# AWK - remove all but last occurance of log file line based on time

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a file that collects option 82 data from our DHCP server. The files contains lines that are similar in all aspects except timestamps, and the server that they came from. I need to remove all "related" lines except for the last occurrance of the similar line based on time.

My raw file looks like this:

```
 Aug  1 16:23:05 serverA dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.1.100 | MAC=70:73:cb:b3:3c:58 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:7d:fe | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:73:4a
 Aug  1 16:24:55 serverB dhcpd: Service B OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.1.100 | MAC=38:71:de:4b:f2:46 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:7d:fe | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:73:4a
 Jul 27 16:37:46 serverA dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.2.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f
 Jul 31 13:20:11 serverB dhcpd: Service B OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.2.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f 
 Jul 27 16:37:46 serverB dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.3.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f
 Jul 31 13:20:11 serverA dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.3.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f
```

After text processing I need to achieve this:

```
  Aug  1 16:24:55 serverB dhcpd: Service B OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.1.100 | MAC=38:71:de:4b:f2:46 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:7d:fe | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:73:4a
  Jul 31 13:20:11 serverB dhcpd: Service B OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.2.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f
  Jul 31 13:20:11 serverA dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.3.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f
```

Here are a few things I have tried so far, but these seem to remove all instances of certain lines, and the finished file is missing data that we need.

```
 /bin/awk '!_[$9]++' rawfile
 /bin/awk 'NR == FNR {if (z[$9]) y[z[$9]]; z[$9] = FNR; next} !(FNR in y)' rawfile rawfile
 tac rawfile | awk '!seen[$9]++' | tac > finished_file
```

I'm in no way an expert on awk. I've found and tried these by just googling, so any help I could get would be greatly appreciated. And, I'm open to other text processing tools, not just awk.

Comment: *"similar in all aspects except timestamps"* Could you be more specific? The lines you showed have many more differences than just the timestamps... I see `serverA` vs `serverB`, `Service A` vs `Service B`, and the MAC. Maybe you want to invert the logic and only match on specific fields? Also, how should the code decide to keep lines 4 and 6 of your sample input, when your last four lines are so similar?

Comment: Server A, Server B and the Service names are all just masked for privacy. But there are only 2 servers and only 2 services. I was thinking we'd need to key off of the IP address, or the circuit or remote ID as these are the fields that will for the most part always be the same.

Comment: And, to answer your last question, if we key off IP, the code would need to look at all of the lines with the same IP, then keep only the last occurance of that line by timestamp.

Comment: Sorry, but *"I was thinking X or Y"* and *"for the most part always"* are not clear enough rules for a computer to execute...

Comment: OK, easy. Lets assume the IP address is a constant then.

Comment: Ok, you haven't said anything about what order the input file is in or why the timestamps in your example are out of order, but here's an example that prints only each last line when groups of lines have the same IP (the last line of the file is always printed; lines without IP's are ignored): `perl -nle '/\bIP\s*=\s*(\S+)\b/||next;print $a if $.>1 && $b ne $1;$a=$_;$b=$1;eof&&print' input.txt` - if that's not enough, you'll have to show a more representative sample of your input data.

Comment: Yea, that's my bad. The lines will be ordered from earliest to latest time in the input file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments, the input file is actually ordered by timestamps in ascending order, and you want to match on the IP.

```
$ cat input.txt 
 Aug  1 16:23:05 serverA dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.1.100 | MAC=70:73:cb:b3:3c:58 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:7d:fe | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:73:4a
 Aug  1 16:24:55 serverB dhcpd: Service B OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.1.100 | MAC=38:71:de:4b:f2:46 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:7d:fe | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:73:4a
 Jul 27 16:37:46 serverA dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.2.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f
 Jul 27 16:37:46 serverB dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.3.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f
 Jul 31 13:20:11 serverB dhcpd: Service B OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.2.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f 
 Jul 31 13:20:11 serverA dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.3.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f
$ perl -ne '/\bIP\s*=\s*([\d.]+)\b/||next;$x{$1}=$_}{print $x{$_} for sort keys %x' input.txt 
 Aug  1 16:24:55 serverB dhcpd: Service B OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.1.100 | MAC=38:71:de:4b:f2:46 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:7d:fe | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:73:4a
 Jul 31 13:20:11 serverB dhcpd: Service B OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.2.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f 
 Jul 31 13:20:11 serverA dhcpd: Service A OPTION-82 | IP =192.168.3.100 | MAC=3c:90:66:64:c7:20 | CIRCUIT-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:a2:37 | REMOTE-ID=0a:00:3e:bb:c1:3f
```

Note: `sort keys %x` isn't perfect, as it will sort the lines alphabetically. If you need the same order as in the original file, please specify, and as I said in the comments, show a more representative sample of input (and output) data. See also [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).